# bootstrap modal opens but not visible

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues with the Bootstrap modal, it opens but is not visible. However it has all of the elements there.

Here is the code:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary backcolor"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <span>View Profile</span></button>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y7xfb5a1/1/ ?

Comment: We can't really give you a specific answer as you've not shown enough information about the problem and what you've shown should work without any issues. That said, check that the `z-index` of the element is high enough to appear over any content in your page.

Comment: Possible problem with position or z-index?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What else would you suggest I add? I have tried changing the z-index with no luck.

Comment: There's lots of reasons this may not be working. It's near impossible to diagnose without seeing a working example of the problem. Have you at least checked the console for errors?

Comment: @erikscandola thanks man, it was the position set to it

Comment: you should provide a fiddle exemple to get help :)

Comment: @QuentinRoger Ahh right, thank you! I'll keep that in mind for next time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine for me..

```html
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary backcolor"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <span>View Profile</span></button>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In My case the whole modal was style to "opacity: 0" . That's why I was facing this problem. Check on your Css if there is any opacity: 0 or display: none or something that makes the modal invisible.